# Java cant find class

Tags: java, class

When i type in a simple code, i get an error code that i cannot understand.

The code is:
import static java.lang.System.out;

class UseAccount
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

```
    fred myAccount = new fred();
    fred yourAccount = new fred();

    myAccount.name = "Barry Burd";
    myAccount.address = "222 Cyberspace Lane";
    myAccount.balance = 24.02;

    yourAccount.name = "Jane Q. Public";
    yourAccount.address = "111 Consumer Street";
    yourAccount.balance = 55.63;

        myAccount.display();
        out.println();
        yourAccout.display();
}
```

}

however when i try to compile the code i simply get:

```
account2.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class fred
location: class UseAccount
        fred yourAccount = new fred();
        ^
```

How can i fix this error?

i am just starting to learn java and this code is directly from a tutorial. According to the tutorial using "fred myAccount = new fred();" and "fred yourAccount = new fred();" does define the classes and the information below this section of code fills in the information.

Comment: do you have a class `fred` that is accessible here ?

Comment: Do you have your class `fred` somewhere accessible? And please, post your complete code, not just some snippet.

Comment: Have you gone through the basic "Hello world" example in Java? To me, your code looks like in C++

Comment: Where is the fred class defined? Is it in another java file? What does it look like?

Comment: bell That error is basically saying that it can't find a class called fred. Post the class code for fred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, you need a file Fred.java (you should use a capital letter name, although java doesn't *require* it) that has at least

```
 class Fred {
 }
```

then you'll need to fill it in to have it do something.

Better yet, name the class Account.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile your class using the compiled class `fred`.

Have you considered using an IDE, it can help you start writing code, father.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to successfully compile:

1. The class/package must be [imported](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) into the class where you use it
2. The class/library must be in the [classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) (see [the technote](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) also)